# Facebook url redirects to play store

Tags: android, facebook, url

In my android app I am sharing a website url as link. Shared url redirects properly in brower as well as ios native facebook app.But when we take the same from android facebook native app it redirects to playstore.Why this happens?
Thank you

Comment: What is the website URL do you have problem with? Maybe it has something to do with domain.

Comment: even google url is not coming

Comment: params.putString("link", "http://www.google.com");This is the url that i am using.Is there problem with facebook developer settings.Now the app is in development mode

Comment: For proper deep linking from Android, you need to specify both a package name (e.g. com.my.namespace) AND a fully qualified class name (e.g. com.my.namesapce.MainActivity) in your app settings (in addition to turning on the deep linking option). Are all of these settings correct?

Comment: yes.all that settings are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused because deep linking was enabled in facebook developer account.After disabling that link will redirects to correct url.

Comment: Please, how do you disable deep linking on https://developers.facebook.com/ ? I don't see such option anywhere.